# Android app using SQLite data "Attempt to invoke virtual method '...' on a null object reference"

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am coding an android app and I am having an issue locating my error. I am trying to get data from an SQLite DB. The app runs normally until I call the activity and it crashes.

Here is the code that I have:

error on line    mTerm = mDBHelper.getTerm(((Term) i.getSerializableExtra("term")).getTermId())

Error:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.example...Term.getTermId()' on a null object reference

**Activity**

```
public class TermDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Term mTerm;
private DBOpenHelper mDBHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_term_details);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle("Term Details");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mDBHelper = new DBOpenHelper(this);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    mTerm = mDBHelper.getTerm(((Term) i.getSerializableExtra("term")).getTermId());
    setTextViews();
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.edit).setVisible(true);
    return true;
}

private void setTextViews() {
    TextView Title = findViewById(R.id.term_details_name_value);
    TextView Start = findViewById(R.id.term_start_date_value);
    TextView End = findViewById(R.id.term_end_date_value);
    Title.setText(mTerm.getTermName());
    Start.setText(mTerm.getTermStart());
    End.setText(mTerm.getTermEnd());
}


}
```

My DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper and the tables are created fine. I am able to use the following code to pull data on another activity.

**DBHelper**

```
public Term getTerm(int termId) {
    Term term;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TERMS + " WHERE " + TERM_ID + " = " + 
termId, null);

    res.moveToFirst();
    term = new Term(
            res.getInt(0),
            res.getString(1),
            res.getString(2),
            res.getString(3));
    res.close();
    return term;
}
```

Term Class

```
public class Term implements Serializable {

private int termId;
private String termName;
private String termStart;
private String termEnd;
public Term(int termId, String termName, String termStart, String termEnd){

    this.termId = termId;
    this.termName = termName;
    this.termStart = termStart;
    this.termEnd = termEnd;
}

public int getTermId(){
    return termId;
}

public void setTermId(int termId){
    this.termId = termId;
}
```

Comment: Could you share the line on the code that the exception is generated? It looks like a NullPointerException there are a couple of suspects but it'd help to know the line originating the error.

Comment: sure in onCreate()  mTerm = mDBHelper.getTerm(((Term) 
 i.getSerializableExtra("term")).getTermId());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try extracting the Term to a variable before using it in DBHelper. I suspect the extra is missing and when the call to *getSerializableExtra* returns the *getTermId* is called on null, causing the Exception.

Edit:

This is what I mean by extracting to a variable:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Term term = i.getSerializableExtra("term"); // <- this might be null
// Place a breakpoint on the next line to verify
mTerm = mDBHelper.getTerm(term.getTermId());
```

Comment: I am very new to this and I'm not entirely sure how to extract Term into a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I still get a NullPointerException on mTerm = mDBHelper.getTerm(term.getTermId());    the error is Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int ...Term.getTermId()' on a null object reference. could there be an issue with the Term class?

Comment: That was expected, I think you are not sending the "term" extra to the new activity. The class that calls startActivity for the TermDetailsActivity should be adding that extra before starting the activity.

Comment: I am using an onItemClick (AdapterView...) on the calling activity using the following Term mTerm = (Term) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                        switchActivity(TermDetailsActivity.class, null, mTerm);

Comment: I found my issue. I had a typo that was calling the wrong variable in the calling activity. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!!!